# Chrome Extensions: How do you gray out icon depending on the url?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Does chrome have an api to disable (and thus gray out) chrome extensions on certain urls or do I just have to have a if statement that checks the url and switches out the icon accordingly?

Comment: Looks like I do have to check for the url manually.  Too bad Chrome Extensions can't do this in the manifest.json.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent), it allows you to show [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) depending on the URL of a web page and the CSS selectors its content matches.

You could create conditions ( yes, you could use regex) and actions ( [`ShowPageAction`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-ShowPageAction) [`SetIcon`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-SetIcon)) via a constructor like `new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher` and `new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()`. Detailed sample are listed in the [api documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent).

```
var rule2 = {
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: { hostEquals: 'www.google.com', schemes: ['https'] },
      css: ["input[type='password']"]
    }),
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      css: ["video"]
    })
  ],
  actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule2]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

add to manifest.js:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
"content_scripts" :[
    {
      "matches" : [
        "*://*.example.com/*"
      ],
      "js" : ["main.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_idle"

    }
  ]
```

main.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:'showPageAction'});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
    if(message.type === 'showPageAction'){
        chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You use [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) instead of [browserAction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), but there are some things to note:

According to my test, you cannot use "<all_urls>" and "activeTab" in "content_scripts" and "Permissions", otherwise the icon will always be colored.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],   //  error
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }
],
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "declarativeContent"],    //  error
```

**narrow down**

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }
],
"permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "declarativeContent"],
```

**background.js**

```js
let rule1 = {
  conditions: [
    new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: { hostEquals: '127.0.0.1' },
    }),
  ],
  actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()],
};

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, data => {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([rule1], data => {
    console.log('addRules', data);
  });
});
```

`The removeRules operation is performed because the rule will be added repeatedly every time the extension is refreshed.`

Reference question link

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63434774/9854149