# Chrome Extension Dev: How to gray out the Icon onClick?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to Gray out my extension with this code snippet.

#### background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    alert('OnClick Listener');
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      file: 'content.js'
    })
    chrome.pageAction.hide(tab.id);
    console.log(`tab.id: ${tab.id}`);
  });
}
```

This code allows me to click only once on my extension icon, which for now is totally fine.

calling `hide` does disable my extension, however the icon doesn't go back to `grayscale`. I even tried to reset it by using `chrome.pageAction.setIcon` in order to force refresh, but it was still `coloured`.

I am aware of [Chrome Extensions: How do you gray out icon depending on the url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794273/chrome-extensions-how-do-you-gray-out-icon-depending-on-the-url/38799886#38799886), but I don't think that what I am looking for.

Comment: The page action API is meaningless in modern Chrome, it does not gray out icons if your manifest.json has permissions for the tab e.g. activeTab or a URL pattern. Don't use page action, use `browser_action`.

Comment: I was not able to gray out the icon with `browser_action` in my first attempts. From what you said, I am understanding it is possible. I will do another attempt ASAP.

Comment: Inspect the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: Thanks! I will be checking for a demo with this feature now. If you have one in mind, please let me know.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I checked the `manifest.json` of all samples containing `declarativeContent`. All of them uses `page_action`.

Comment: There's no need for declarativeContent with browser_action.

Comment: The only way to gray out the icon in modern Chrome is to use URL patterns for individual sites, not broad patterns like `<all_urls>`  or `http://*/*` etc.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it programmatically. Not using patterns. Are you saying that it is not possible to do it programmatically and the only way is to use patterns, and exclusively with URL patterns?

Comment: [page_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) description mentions the possibility to gray out the icon when inactive, but [browser_action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) does not.

Comment: The documentation for page_action is obsolete, just like the API itself. You can use [chrome.permissions API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) instead to enable URL dynamically, which will "ungray" the icon.

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#files) doesn't present `page_action` as old, let alone the `browser_action` as a new way of doing things. Where do people get it from? Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: The documentation for extensions has been always poorly maintained. What I'm telling you is based on the real state of affairs as seen from the chromium source code, actual browser behavior and https://crbug.com observations.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, you cannot use "<all_urls>" and "activeTab" in "content_scripts" and "Permissions", otherwise the icon will always be colored.

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],   //  error
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }
],
"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "activeTab", "storage", "tabs", "declarativeContent"],    //  error
```

**narrow down**

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1/*"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
  }
],
"permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "declarativeContent"],
```